# Set color to grey for points below some cutoff when plotting with palette in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Sorry for the long and probably poor title.

I am trying to plot some data in gnuplot, where the data file has the format

```
x       y       z
1.0     1.5     0.1
1.3     1.8     0.7
2.1     3.7     1.1
3.1     4.3     1.5
3.7     4.7     1.8
```

I want to plot y vs. x and, for each point, indicate the value of z by the color of the point. Currently I use the following code for this:

```
size = 0.5
type = 7
set term pngcairo 
set output 'Foo.png'
set palette rgbformulae 22,13,-31
set cblabel "z"
unset key
set xlabel 'x'
set ylabel 'y'
set title 'y vs. x'
plot "Data.txt" u 1:2:3 w p pt type ps size palette
```

This works, but I would like to make the following change: For each point whose z value is below a cutoff, say 1.0, I want the color to be set to grey, regardless of the z-value. Then for z-values greater than or equal to the cutoff, I want the color to be picked from the palette according to the z-value.

Thus, I want the color to go discontinuously from grey to blue (for the current palette) at the cutoff value. Can this be done, and if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to do with a palette based on rgbformulae.  It's relatively easy with a defined palette.  Here is an example that gives a palette close to what you chose, with a dark gray tacked on at the bottom end.  `cbrange` is then set so that your z cutoff is the minimum.  All z values below cbmin will be assigned the endpoint value, which is dark gray in this case.

```
set xrange [0:1]; set yrange [0:pi]
set sample 100; set isosample 100
set palette defined (-0.01 "grey20", 0 "blue", 0.4 "green", 0.6 "yellow", 1.0 "red")

zmin = -0.6
set cbrange [zmin: *]
set xyplane at zmin
splot cos(x)*sin(y+y*(x*x)) with pm3d
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's very nice! When I add your suggested palette and the appropriate cbrange, the grey value shows up at the very bottom of my color scale on the right. Do you know if there is any way to remove this?

Comment: Not really.  You could maybe make it an even thinner slice of the palette.  Instead of `-0.01 "grey20"`, maybe use `-0.001 "grey20"`.  However I think the slice that shows in the color bar will never be less than 1/128 of the total height.

Answer (score 3):

After gnuplot 5.4, this can be achieved by using the function "palette()" in "using" and combining it with the "with point lc rgb variable".

```
size = 3 ### 0.5 in original code 
type = 7
set term pngcairo 
set output 'Foo.png'
set palette rgbformulae 22,13,-31
set cblabel "z"
unset key
set xlabel 'x'
set ylabel 'y'
set title 'y vs. x'

set cbrange [0:2]  ### this is required by palette() function
gray = 0x808080    ### gray color expressed by integer

plot NaN w p palette, \
     "Data.txt" u 1:2:($3<1 ? gray : palette($3)) w p pt type ps size lc rgb variable
```

The RGB value passed to "lc rgb variable" are determined by comparing $3 with threshold value 1(for example).

"NaN w p palette" is a dummy plot, a technique for forcing the colorbox to appear. Without it, the colorbox will not be displayed.

[image]

Comment: should be mentioned, I guess the `palette()` function only exists since gnuplot 5.4.0, not in gnuplot 5.2.8

Comment: Thank you for your reply! My gnuplot version is 5.2 (with no possibility to upgrade, it seems) so I cannot try your solution (see the comment by @theozh). I have therefore accepted the answer by Ethan.

Comment: @theozh 'palette(z)' function seems to be added at Feb, 2020 (after 5.2.8). I updated the answer. Thank you pointing this out.

Comment: @AlexandreVandermonde I'm sorry to hear that you can't try it at the moment. If you have a chance to upgrade gnuplot, you can do something like the answer. Thanks for your reply, including an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a gnuplot 5.2 version. You can use a rgbformulae palette.
It uses the datablock `$PALETTE` which is created after carrying out the command `test palette`.

**Code:** (tested with gnuplot as low as 5.2.0)

```
### cut-off colors for a given rgbformulae palette (gnuplot >=5.2)
reset session

# create some test data
set xrange [-5:5]
set yrange [-5:5]
set samples 50
set isosamples 50
set table $Data 
    splot (sin(1.3*x)*cos(.9*y)+cos(.8*x)*sin(1.9*y)+cos(y*.2*x))*3
unset table

set palette rgbformulae 22,13,-31
test palette   # necessary to put the palette into the datablock $PALETTE
myColorMin = 0
myColorMax = 6
myOutOfRangeColor = 0x808080
myColorPos(c) = int(255.0 * (c-myColorMin)/(myColorMax - myColorMin))+1
myColor(c) = c<myColorMin || c>myColorMax ? myOutOfRangeColor : \
             (int(word($PALETTE[myColorPos(c)],2)*0xff)<<16) + \
             (int(word($PALETTE[myColorPos(c)],3)*0xff)<<8) + \
             (int(word($PALETTE[myColorPos(c)],4)*0xff))

set cbrange [myColorMin:myColorMax]
set view 36, 72
set ztics 5

splot $Data u 1:2:3:(myColor($3)) w pm3d  lc rgb variable notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's very nice! I'll probably keep Ethan's answer as the accepted one, since he was first and since it is not so important whether or not I use the rgbformula palette.