# Handling out-of-range values with GNUPlot's splot

Tags: gnuplot

I use the splot commadn to produce a heat map of the earth. The x- and y-values represent lattitude and longitude of a specific point on the Earth's surface, while the related z-value is the outcome of an analysis. The zrange is between 0 and 60. However, for some locations on Earth, there is no result available (which is correct) and z is set to 9999 for these cases.

I'm using the following script to produce the heat map:

```
set terminal png large size 1600,\
1200 font arial 24 crop
set output "map.png"
set palette model RGB defined (0 "dark-green",1 "forest-green",2 "green",3 "light-green",4 "dark-yellow",5 "yellow",6 "red",7 "dark-red")

set xrange[-180.00: 180.00]
set yrange[ -90.00:  90.00]
set zrange[ *: 60]

set grid
set pm3d map
set xlabel "Longitude [deg]"
set ylabel "Latitude [deg]"
unset key
set cblabel "Time [h]"
splot "output\\map.dat" u 5:6:8,\
"input\\world.dat" u 1:2:(    .00) w l lw 1 lt -1
```

It works fine but because of the limitation in zrange, regions with z > 60 are shown in white.
I want to have something like a condition which enables that all 9999 z-values are shown in a specific colour like purple with a declaration like "no result" in the legend.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,
Florian

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set color to grey for points below some cutoff when plotting with palette in Gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64813524/set-color-to-grey-for-points-below-some-cutoff-when-plotting-with-palette-in-gnu)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, I cannot transfer this to my application as I am quite new to GNUPlot.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal dataset for testing? Which gnuplot version are you running?

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to have 3 "ranges" of colors:

- `0` to `60` your defined palette colors
- `>60` "out of range" color
- `=9999` "no data" color

Not sure if `splot ... w pm3d` will allow an easy "independent" setting for z and color.
Furthermore, if you have NxN datapoints you will get (N-1)x(N-1) quadrangles and the color is determined by the z-values of the involved vertices (check `help corners2color`) and http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.5/pm3d.html (the very last graph). Maybe there is an easy way which I am not aware of.

That's why I would perfer the plotting style `with boxxyerror` (check `help boxxyerror`), maybe this is not the intended way, but it is rather flexible. If you are running gnuplt 5.4 you have the function `palette()` (check `help palette`).

I would take for missing data (backgroundcolor here:white) and for data out of range "grey", but you can easily change it. You can skip the random data generation part and in the plot command replace `$Data` with your filename and the corresponding columns. As well, replace `180./N` and `90./N` with the width (delta longitude) and height (delta latitude) of one data element.

**Script:** (requires gnuplot>=5.4)

```
### define separate color for missing values
reset session

set xrange[-180:180]
set yrange[-90:90]

# create some "random" test data
N = 90
set samples N
set isosamples N
set table $Data
    c = 0.05
    x0 =  70  # (rand(0)*360-180) # or random
    y0 = -50  # (rand(0)*180-90)  #
    size0 = 2
    x1 = -150 # (rand(0)*360-180) # or random
    y1 =  -20 # (rand(0)*180-90)  #
    size1 = 1
    holeP0(x,y) = (1-erf((x-x0)*c/size0)**2) * (1-erf((y-y0)*c/size0)**2)
    holeP1(x,y) = (1-erf((x-x1)*c/size1)**2) * (1-erf((y-y1)*c/size1)**2)
    f(x,y) = rand(0)<holeP0(x,y) || rand(0)<holeP1(x,y) ? 9999 : (sin(1.3*x*c)*cos(.9*y*c)+cos(.8*x*c)*sin(1.9*y*c)+cos(y*.2*x*c**2))*11.5+33
    splot f(x,y)
unset table

set palette model RGB defined (0 "dark-green",1 "forest-green",2 "green",3 "light-green",4 "dark-yellow",5 "yellow",6 "red",7 "dark-red")

myZmin            =  0
myZmax            = 60
myColorNoData     = 0xffffff
myColorOutOfRange = 0x999999

set rmargin screen 0.8
set colorbox user origin screen 0.85,graph 0.2 size graph 0.05,graph 0.8
set cblabel "Amplitude"
set cbrange [myZmin:myZmax]
set tics out
set style fill solid 1.0 border
set key noautotitle at graph 1.27, graph 0.15 reverse Left samplen 2

myColor(col) = (z=column(col), z==9999 ? myColorNoData : z>myZmax ? myColorOutOfRange : palette(z))

plot $Data u 1:2:(180./N):(90./N):(myColor(3)) w boxxy lc rgb var, \
      "world.dat" u 1:2:(0) w l lc "black", \
      NaN w l lc palette, \
      keyentry w boxes lc rgb 0x000000 fill empty ti "no data", \
      keyentry w boxes lc rgb myColorOutOfRange ti "\ndata out\nof range"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure how to modify the style for the selected points, but you can use the ternary operator not to draw them at all. Something like:

```
splot "output\\map.dat" u 5:6:(($8<=60)?($8):(1/0))
```